# Is there a Linux console command line MVC framework?

Tags: linux, model-view-controller, console

Is there a framework for developing Linux console application, where controllers are console commands and views are their stdout output?

Comment: I have heard of GUI apps that go on top of command line. For instance, a CD burning program would call a command-line one under the hood. Going the other way - you can send commands from the console which control OOffice.org,s GUI (I believe). Apple's automater and Windows's PowerShell use a similar idea. However, I cannot think of a good reason why one would want GUI at all if the input is on stdin, and the output is on stdout. Did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: As far as I've understood you, Hamish, you indeed have misundersood my question. I mean no GUI. I seek right the opposite - to do everything from command line. Everything.

Comment: I suppose about something based on CQRS and having package manager as dependency manager... I was thinking about this, all the overlay we carry on on business logic because we simply start from the http layer.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using Python, the [`cmd` module](http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html) might be worth looking into.

Comment: Yes, now I indeed see this the only candidate. Maybe I can modify (or maybe, it's not needed even - I haven't got any Python experience yet) Django to use command line instead of HTTP.